# QT5 C++, Is there a way I can get the current text of a widget within a qlist container

Tags: c++, combobox, qt5, qwidget, qlist

I need to retrieve the text in the order in which they appear on the user form. I am trying as below:

```
    QString line = "QLineEdit";
    QString combo = "QComboBox";
    QList<QWidget *> childWidgets = ui->frame_3->findChildren<QWidget *>();
    QStringList data;

    for(auto widget : childWidgets){
        if(widget->metaObject()->className() == line || widget->metaObject()->className() == combo){
            data.append(widget->text()); //append the text of the lineEdits and ComboBoxes to data
        }
    }
```

I get the following compile error from the above code:

> "no member named 'text' in QWidget

Comment: My difficulty is with this line of code: data.append(widget->text());

Comment: What is the problem with that?

Comment: It returns "no member named 'text' in QWidget

Comment: I understand now.

Comment: Is there anything I'm missing please?

Answer (score 1):

Since you pointed out the QWidget base class does not have a text member function you will need to access the QComboBox and QLineEdit directly to get the current text.

```
QList<QWidget *> childWidgets = ui->frame_3->findChildren<QWidget *>();
QStringList data;

for(auto widget : childWidgets){
    auto combo = dynamic_cast<QComboBox*>(widget); 
    if (combo) {
       data << combo->currentText(); // currentText() returns the text from the combobox
    }
    else {
        auto lineEdit = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit*>(widget);
        if (lineEdit) {
            data << lineEdit->text(); // A line edit has a text() member.
        }
    }
}
```

This code does not handle ordering. I believe the order is in the same order as added to the parent.

Comment: There may be a delay before you can do so. I am not sure I have only asked 1 question and that was many years ago.

Comment: Just like you mentioned, the code gets the data but does not do any sort of ordering.